# Why is the metal tab of a BJT power transistor is always connected to its collector pin?

Tags: power, bjt, heat

Until now I thought the metal tab of a BJT power transistor is connected to ground but it seems like it is connected to its own collector pin´as shown in the below illustration:

[image]

Is there a particular reason for this?

Comment: Transistors don't have a 'ground pin'.

Comment: Sorry my foolishness. I think I mixed up with voltage TO-220 regulator.

Comment: Be VERY careful about assuming that's true of all voltage regulators...

Comment: It is connected to the base time to time for low power transistors.

Answer (score 9):

The electrical connection at the bottom of the diagram also makes a good thermal connection. Very important for a power transistor.

So, why can't you just reverse the Emitter and Collector in the diagram. You could, but it would be a lousy transistor.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor#Structure

> The collector surrounds the emitter region, making it almost
>   impossible for the electrons injected into the base region to escape
>   without being collected, thus making the resulting value of α very
>   close to unity, and so, giving the transistor a large β.

[image]

Comment: Oh My! I'm just an amateur, and the idea that current flows in the direction of the arrows is so ingrained in my mind,... I never stopped to wonder what the words "emitter" and "collector" actually meant!

Answer (score 4):

If you can access the website Wikipedia, [see the article titled *2N3055*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2N3055).  Scroll down the page to the figure titled [2N3055 transistor internals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2N3055#/media/File:PowerTransistor_2N3055_1.jpg); it shows how this particular power NPN transistor is mounted inside a TO-3 case. The collector is the gray colored substrate material (look at the edges of the square shape, and in the "trough" that snakes back-and-forth between the base and emitter, which are on top). The collector is mounted/bonded directly onto the metal can, and this is why the collector voltage is present on the metal can.  Bonding the semiconductor die directly to the metal can in this manner optimizes the flow of heat from the semiconductor die—which dissipates power and produces heat—to "the outside world" through the metal can.

For what it's worth, ***many*** electronic component case styles bond the silicon die to a metal pad to facilitate heat flow out of the die—e.g., TO-220, TO-262, leadless chip carrier, just to name a few—and quite often that metal tab has voltage on it.

*(NB: When attaching a metal heat sink to a component, quite often an electrical insulator of some sort is installed between the component's metal pad and the metal heat sink, and special fastening hardware is used, to ensure the heat sink is galvanically isolated from the voltage on the component's metal pad.  For example, try an Internet search using "TO-3 insulator kit". In this way a single block of metal can be used as the heat sink for multiple electronic components, and if necessary (for operator / equipment safety reasons) the metal heat sink can be electrically bonded to ground potential.)*

*(NB: A specially-engineered material called* thermal grease *(a.k.a., thermal compound, thermal paste, heat sink compound) is used in some heat sink applications when attaching a heat sink to an electronic component. If air is trapped between a component and its heat sink, the air acts as a thermal insulator and limits the flow of heat from the component into the heat sink. If this happens, heat gets trapped and accumulates within the component, and the component can be damaged or destroyed as a consequence of excessive heat buildup. Therefore, thermal grease is applied to the various mating surfaces to remove/replace as much air as possible between the mating surfaces and thereby optimize the flow of heat out of the component and into the heat sink.)*

Answer (score 2):

Collector receives both majority charge carriers from base and emitter. The collector is also the widest section. Thus, connecting it to the external heatsink, metal conjunction facilitates better heat transfer to the environment.

Answer (score 1):

Note that not all power transistors have the case or tab connected to the collector, some RF power transistors have the case connected to the emitter. This provides a lower inductance path to RF ground, which in an RF amplifier is critical to maximize gain.